# What is qobject_cast?

Tags: c++, qt, dynamic-cast, qobject

Could someone explain in as simple terms as possible (or as simple as you would like) what `qobject_cast` is, what it does and why we would need to cast one class type to another?

Like, I get typecasting in the sense of casting an `int` as a `char` or `QString` maybe to use `QMessageBox`, but why cast into different classes?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Before you start learning what [`qobject_cast`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast) is, you would need to know what C++'s [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) is. Dynamic cast is all about [polymorphism](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/).

C++'s dynamic cast uses [RTTI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) (Run Time Type Information) to cast an object. But `qobject_cast` does this without RTTI.

#### What is dynamic cast?

For example suppose we've got a car factory function. Like this:

```
Car* make_car(string brand){
    if(brand == "BMW"){
        return new BmwCar;
    }
    if(brand == "Audi"){
        return new AudiCar;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Note that `BmwCar` and `AudiCar` classes inherit `Car` class. Using this function we can make different cars only using one function. For example:

```
string brand;
cin >> brand;
Car *car = make_car(brand);

BmwCar *bmw = dynamic_cast<BmwCar*>(car);
if (bmw != nullptr) {
    cout << "You've got a BMW!";
}

AudiCar *audi = dynamic_cast<AudiCar*>(car);
if (audi != nullptr) {
    cout << "You've got a Audi!";
}
```

Without `dynamic_cast` you won't be able to determine if `car` is a `BmwCar` or an `AudiCar`.

#### What is different between `dynamic_cast` and `qobject_cast`?

- `qobject_cast` can only be used with [`QObject`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html) derived classes having [`Q_OBJECT`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT) macro.
- `qobject_cast` doesn't use RTTI.

Comment: Be careful, RTTI will not work on most compilers if your based classes don't have virtual methods.

Answer (score 31):

[`qobject_cast`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast) is same thing as [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast), but works only for children of `QObject`. It doesn't require [RTTI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) and it works much faster, because it is not possible to use `QObject` in [multiple inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance).

Don't hesitate to do self-research and to read some basic things about OOP and C++. Especially about polymorphism. And don't hestiate to read Qt documentation, it contains a lot of easy-to-understand examples.

A resent usage of [`qobject_cast`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast) is getting a pointer to a class inside a slot:

```
QObject::connect( btn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MyClass::onClicked );
void MyClass::onClicked()
{
    // How to get pointer to a button:
    QObject *p = sender();
    // It's QObject. Now we need to cast it to button:
    QPushButton *btn = qobject_cast<QPushButon *>( p );
    Q_ASSERT( btn != nullptr ); // Check that a cast was successfull
    // Now we can use a QObject as a button:
    btn->setText( "We just clicked on a button!" );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!! I have found the resources that explain how I should use it and what it does, but I haven't found any explanation for when I would use it. I am basically using it because either the example I am emulating has used it or I have been told to use it. In what scenario would I go "I think qobject_cast/dynamic_cast is the way forward"

Comment: Just added a sample. If you don't understand where to use it - don't use it.  It is not nesessary to use all stuff from Qt ;)

Comment: @MichaelThomas TL;DR: You'll know when you need it. In many cases, properly decoupled code won't ever need it. I consider it a code smell and try to avoid using it gratuitously. That you haven't had a need for it is usually a good sign! Keep it that way.

Comment: Great! qobject_cast, a faster version of dynamic_cast, but only applies for QObject.

Comment: Is there a Qt version of `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`, i.e. for use with _smart_ pointers, such as `std::shared_ptr`, instead of raw pointers?

Comment: @Will can you explain what you want to achieve? QObject-based classes usually don't need smart pointers.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov Coming from a position of using only smart pointers and moving to Qt, I am trying to figure out how/when to use smart pointers as much as possible in a Qt environment. Wondering whether smart pointers will come to Qt at all or whether it's safe to just rely on the QObject parent mechanism for managing the memory of all children.

Comment: @Will I recommend you to read Qt docs about memory management. They have their own concept, it is not a smart pointer way: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/objecttrees.html . So create objects on heap with `new` and don't forget to set the parent. QObject internals will manage the lifetime of child objects by itself.