# In Qt with C++, what is the best way to access private members belonging to MainWindow, in a Dialog?

Tags: c++, qt5

As a beginner in Qt with C++, I am having difficulty in accessing members of my MainWindow object from a Dialog object.

My dialog object is from a class called Month, and below is my code:

I have a comboBox in MainWindow where I want the user to select a month, and then store the string for that month in a private variable called monthSelected as follows:

> ```
> void MainWindow::on_monthComboBox_activated(const QString &arg1)
> {
>     monthSelected = arg1;
>     qDebug()<<"Month Selected is " << monthSelected << endl;
> }
> ```

I get the correct output after selecting the month, but when I try to retrieve the value of monthSelected in my Month dialog class via a getter function, then I get an empty string as output.

> ```
> Month::Month(QWidget *parent) :
>     QDialog(parent),
>     ui(new Ui::Month)
> {
>     ui->setupUi(this);
>
>     MainWindow *mainWindow = new MainWindow();
>
>     qDebug()<<mainWindow->getMonthSelected();
> }
> ```

As you can see, I created a pointer to MainWindow in order to access the getter function in my Month class, and I suspect this is where my error lies.

Is this the correct way to access members from the MainWindow class in a dialog, and if not, how would I go about doing it correctly?

Comment: Why are you creating a new instance of MainWindow? That is not going to help at all this is a totally new object having nothing to do with the already existing MainWindow from your application.

Comment: Maybe the `parent` pointer is already the MainWindow? Who creates the `Month` object?

Comment: @drescherjm The Month object is created by the MainWindow when the user clicks on a button in the main window. **Month *monthDialog = new Month(this);**

Comment: Then you already have a pointer to your MainWindow.

Comment: `MainWindow* pMain = qobject_cast<MainWindow*>(parent);`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43994584/what-is-qobject-cast

Comment: Thanks for this. How would I then go about referencing the already existing pointer (and accessing its members) in the Month class?

Comment: parent() returns the parent pointer at any time. See here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#parent

Comment: With this said you probably want to use signals and slots for what you are doing.

Comment: I have always just retrieved the value chosen by the dialog from the parent. I believe this is the design intent and so easy. Setting a value in the parent would be, as you have found, much more difficult.

Comment: @drescherjm I've tried using parent to access MainWindow's member functions, but to no avail. None of the functions in MainWindow is available when using parent.

Comment: Did you do this? `MainWindow* pMain = qobject_cast<MainWindow*>(parent);`

Comment: Or when outside the constructor `MainWindow* pMain = qobject_cast<MainWindow*>(parent());`

Comment: @drescherjm I've used **MainWindow* pMain = qobject_cast<MainWindow*>(parent);** and it works now, thank you so much. Still new to QT and C++, so I'll dive into why this worked, but in the meantime just happy that it does. Cheers!