# How to force a model to update QComboBox when data changed?

Tags: c++, qt, model, qt5, qcombobox

I created model for QComboBox:

```
#ifndef QCOMBOBOXMODEL_H
#define QCOMBOBOXMODEL_H

#include <QModelIndex>


class QComboBoxModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
public:
    QComboBoxModel(QObject *parent=nullptr);
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;
    void populate(const QList<QPair<int,QString>> &values);

private:
    QList<QPair<int,QString>> values;
};

#endif // QCOMBOBOXMODEL_H
```

code

```
#include "qcomboboxmodel.h"

#include <QModelIndex>

QComboBoxModel::QComboBoxModel(QObject *parent)
    :QAbstractListModel(parent)
{
}

int QComboBoxModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &) const
{
    return values.count();
}


QVariant QComboBoxModel::data( const QModelIndex &index, int role ) const
{        

    QVariant value;

        switch ( role )
        {
            case Qt::DisplayRole: //string
            {
                value = this->values.value(index.row()).second;
            }
            break;

            case Qt::UserRole: //data
            {
            value = this->values.value(index.row()).first;
            }
            break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    return value;
}

void QComboBoxModel::populate(const QList<QPair<int,QString>> &values)
{
    this->values = values;
}
```

Now i use it

```
    values.append(QPair<int,QString>(-1,"Select item"));
    values.append(QPair<int,QString>(10,"item1(0)"));
    values.append(QPair<int,QString>(11,"item1(1)"));
    values.append(QPair<int,QString>(21,"item1(2)"));
    values.append(QPair<int,QString>(32,"item1(3)"));
    values.append(QPair<int,QString>(44,"item1(4)"));

    newidx = 50;


    model = new QComboBoxModel();
    model->populate(values);
    this->ui->comboBox->setModel(model);
```

and on button click i add new item to combobox

```
newidx++;
QString strIdx = QString().number(newidx);
values.append(QPair<int,QString>(newidx,"New item("+strIdx+")"));

model = new QComboBoxModel();
model->populate(values);
this->ui->comboBox->setModel(model);
```

Its all seems works just fine, but problem here that i need to recreate model every time i add new item to combobox data

```
model = new QComboBoxModel();
model->populate(values);
this->ui->comboBox->setModel(model);
```

Is that a proper way to do so? Or there are another way to force model update combobox when data updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find solution!

First i add new method to model

```
void QComboBoxModel::append(int index, QString value)
{

    int newRow = this->values.count();

    this->beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), newRow, newRow);

        values.append(QPair<int,QString>(index,value));

    endInsertRows();
}
```

Now on button click method changed to this

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    qDebug() << "Clicked!";

    newidx++;
    QString strIdx = QString().number(newidx);

    model->append(newidx,"new item " + strIdx );
}
```

Point is to use `beginInsertRows` and `endInsertRows` to notify model that data actually changed!

Now all worked as expected!

Now you also can modify append method to batch add rows to it, but i think if you add many rows it better just recreate model and reassign it to combobox.

**Update 1:**

Also keep in mind, that you update `values` `QList` inside model, so if you add

```
qDebug() << values;
```

in `on_pushButton_clicked()` method, you always see

```
(QPair(-1,"Select item"), QPair(10,"item1(0)"), QPair(11,"item1(1)"), QPair(21,"item1(2)"), QPair(32,"item1(3)"), QPair(44,"item1(4)"))
```

**Update 2:**

Also i update `populate` method

```
void QComboBoxModel::populate(const QList<QPair<int,QString>> &newValues)
{
    int oldIdx = this->values.count();
    int newIdx = newValues.count();
    this->beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), oldIdx, newIdx);
        this->values = newValues;
    endInsertRows();
}
```

Now you can just work with `values` list

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    qDebug() << "Clicked!";

    newidx++;
    QString strIdx = QString().number(newidx);

    values.append(QPair<int,QString>(newidx,"new item " + strIdx));
    model->populate(values);

    qDebug() << values;
}
```

**Update 3:**

Now, i find one big problem - i did not use pointer inside model, so when i pass QList to model it just create copy instead use already created, so i rewrite model and other code:

Model

```
#ifndef QCOMBOBOXMODEL_H
#define QCOMBOBOXMODEL_H

#include <QModelIndex>


class QComboBoxModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
public:
    QComboBoxModel(QObject *parent=nullptr);
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;
    void populate(QList<QPair<int,QString>> *newValues);
    void append(int index, QString value);

private:
    QList<QPair<int,QString>> *values;
};

#endif // QCOMBOBOXMODEL_H

#include "qcomboboxmodel.h"

#include <QModelIndex>
#include <QDebug>

QComboBoxModel::QComboBoxModel(QObject *parent)
    :QAbstractListModel(parent)
{
    values = new QList<QPair<int,QString>>();
}

int QComboBoxModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &) const
{
    return values->count();
}


QVariant QComboBoxModel::data( const QModelIndex &index, int role ) const
{        

    QVariant value;

        switch ( role )
        {
            case Qt::DisplayRole: //string
            {
                value = this->values->value(index.row()).second;
            }
            break;

            case Qt::UserRole: //data
            {
            value = this->values->value(index.row()).first;
            }
            break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    return value;
}

void QComboBoxModel::populate(QList<QPair<int,QString>> *newValues)
{
    int oldIdx = this->values->count();
    int newIdx = newValues->count();
    this->beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), oldIdx, newIdx);
        this->values = newValues;
    endInsertRows();
}

void QComboBoxModel::append(int index, QString value)
{

    int newRow = this->values->count();

    this->beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), newRow, newRow);

        values->append(QPair<int,QString>(index,value));

    endInsertRows();
}
```

Main form

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include "qcomboboxmodel.h"

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(int index);

    void on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(const QString &arg1);

    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    int newidx;
    QList<QPair<int,QString>> *values;
    QComboBoxModel *model;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "qcomboboxmodel.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    values = new QList<QPair<int,QString>>();

    values->append(QPair<int,QString>(-1,"Select item"));
    values->append(QPair<int,QString>(10,"item1(0)"));
    values->append(QPair<int,QString>(11,"item1(1)"));
    values->append(QPair<int,QString>(21,"item1(2)"));
    values->append(QPair<int,QString>(32,"item1(3)"));
    values->append(QPair<int,QString>(44,"item1(4)"));

    newidx = 50;


    model = new QComboBoxModel();
    model->populate(values);
    this->ui->comboBox->setModel(model);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(int index)
{
    qDebug() << ui->comboBox->itemData(index).value<int>();
}

void MainWindow::on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    qDebug() << arg1;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    qDebug() << "Clicked!";

    newidx++;
    QString strIdx = QString().number(newidx);

    values->append(QPair<int,QString>(newidx,"new item " + strIdx));
    model->populate(values);

    qDebug() << values->toStdList();
}
```

Now all looks just fine and works as intended!

Answer (score 3):

According to "Model Subclassing Reference" in the documentation you have to do many more things to make an editable model. Is there a reason why you don't use a ready made model like QStandardItemModel?

```
    comboModel = new QStandardItemModel(0, 2, this);
    ui->comboBox1->setModel(comboModel);
    comboModel->insertRow(0);
    comboModel->setData(comboModel->index(0, 0), -1);
    comboModel->setData(comboModel->index(0, 1), "Select item");
        //and so on
    //and the data is available as
    int number = comboModel->data(comboModel->index(0, 0)).toInt();
    QString itemtext = comboModel->data(comboModel->index(0, 1)).toString();
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you request the current model via "QAbstractItemModel *   model() const" from the QComboBox; alter it and assign it again (via "void QComboBox::setModel(QAbstractItemModel *model)")?

Comment: nope, it does not work     QComboBoxModel *m = (QComboBoxModel *)this->ui->comboBox->model();
    this->ui->comboBox->setModel(m);

Comment: What is the specific error/problem? Why do you cast and don't keep the base-class? (By the way: C-Style casts are not CPP-like: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43994584/what-is-qobject-cast ) 'auto' is your friend.

Comment: I've just given it a try. The QComboBox comes from an ui-file (first line..). Then changed the value of the first item.

`    auto* cb = ui->myCB;
    cb->insertItem(0, "foo");
    cb->insertItem(1, "bar");
    auto* model = cb->model();
    model->setData(model->index(0,0), "not foo");
    cb->setModel(model);`

Comment: There no errors point is best practice, i need to update "values" and then just update combobox with model update. I try different approach but it did not work. You suggest use of setData but i dont want use that complex approach, i need just to add new element to array and then update combobox.

Comment: Ok, do like this     QComboBoxModel *m = dynamic_cast<QComboBoxModel*>(ui->comboBox->model());
    m->populate(values);
    this->ui->comboBox->setModel(m); it seems work fine, but there a bug, when i press button it add items to cb, but when i open combobox to check items and after that try to add more, it did not add new items :(